# How might I get the list of firms that do not pay dividends?

Tags: python, finance, yfinance

The following code is meant to narrow down the list of the tickers of public companies
that have Bitcoin on their balance sheet (stored in `list_of_tcks`) to those that do not pay dividends (stored in `leanCompanies`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from yfinance import pdr_override, Ticker
    
def give_me_list_of_no_div_payers(list_of_tcks):
    list_refined = []
    list_of_payers = []
    for t in list_of_tcks:
        if len(Ticker(t).dividends) < 1:
            list_refined.append(t)
        elif len(Ticker(t).dividends) > 0:
            list_of_payers.append(t)            
    return (list_refined, list_of_payers) 

def print_stock_div(ticker):
    print(f"{ticker}:")
    print(Ticker(ticker).dividends)

    
list_of_tcks = ['MSTR', 'TSLA', 'BRPHF', 'VOYG', 'MARA', 'SQ', 'HUT', 'RIOT', 'BITF', 'CORZ', 'COIN', 'BTGGF', 'HIVE', 'ARBKF', 'NEXOF', '', 'BROOK', 'HKD', 'BTBT', 'HSSHF', 'BBKCF', 'DMGGF', 'CLSK', 'HODL', 'ABT', 'DGGXF', 'NPPTF', 'CBIT', 'MELI', 'OTC', 'BNXAF', 'PHUN', 'BTCS', 'FRMO', 'SATO', 'MILE', 'MOGO', 'NTHOL TI']
print(list_of_tcks)
print(len(list_of_tcks))

leanCompanies = give_me_list_of_no_div_payers(list_of_tcks)[0]    
print(leanCompanies)   
fatCompanies = give_me_list_of_no_div_payers(list_of_tcks)[1]     
print("Following is the detailed info on the dividends of the fat companies:") 
for t in fatCompanies:
    print(f"{t}:")
    print(Ticker(t).dividends)
```

I noticed that when there is a positive history of paying dividends
the type of `Ticker(t).dividends` is either `pandas.core.series.Series`.
When the firm has never paid its dividend the type of `Ticker(t).dividends`
is either `pandas.core.series.Series` or a `list`.

**1.** Why are there such two types?

**2.** Is testing for the value of `len(Ticker(t).dividends)` a reliable way of getting the list of firms that do not pay dividends?

**3.** Is there another way of obtaining such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The cause of the two types is because some of the tickers are not found.  If you read the output of your `[0]` print line, you will see that there is a `list` for those that return `- <ticker>: No data found, symbol may be delisted`, and a `pd.Series` where the ticker is available, but there is no dividend.
2. Yes, using `len(Tickers(t).dividends)` is sensible, this output is correct for each ticker in your list.
3. There is no need for a condition your `elif:`, you can use `else:` instead.  As the length of the dividends will either be `0` (to be in `list_refined`) or not (will be in `list_of_payers`).  So you can clean up the code with the following instead:

#Option 1

```
def give_me_list_of_no_div_payers(list_of_tcks):
    list_refined = []
    list_of_payers = []
    for t in list_of_tcks:
        if len(Ticker(t).dividends) == 0:
            list_refined.append(t)
        else:
            list_of_payers.append(t)

    return (list_refined, list_of_payers)
```

#Option 2 - list comprehension

```
def give_me_list_of_no_div_payers_2(list_of_tcks):
    list_refined = []
    list_of_payers = []
    [list_refined.append(t) \
     if len(Ticker(t).dividends) == 0 \
         else list_of_payers.append(t) \
             for t in list_of_tcks ]
    
    return [list_refined, list_of_payers]
```

Other than this I don't know!